# Cannot assign to read only property 'oppUrl' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm building a LWC component to display the list records with url in the record name and I'm getting this error "Cannot assign to read only property 'oppUrl' of object '#'" not sure why I'm getting this

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import fetchOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/ExistingOppInLead.getExistingOpp';

const COLUMNS = [
    {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'oppUrl', type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {
            fieldName: 'Name'
            },
            target: '_blank'
        }
    },
    {label: 'Stage', fieldName: 'StageName', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Close Date', fieldName: 'CloseDate', type: 'date'}
];


export default class ExistingOpportunities extends LightningElement {
    @track lstOpps;
    @api recordId;
    @api result;
    column = COLUMNS;

    connectedCallback(){
        this.getOpportunity();
    }

    getOpportunity(){
        fetchOpportunity({id: this.recordId}).then(data => {
            let url = new URL(window.location.origin);
            data.forEach(opp => {
                opp.oppUrl = url+opp.Id;
                if(opp.Id){
                    
                }  
            });
            this.result = data;
            window.console.log('opp data '+ JSON.stringify(data));
            this.error = undefined;
        }).catch(error=>{
            this.error = error;
            window.console.log('error in the LWC '+error);
            this.result = undefined;
        });
    }
    handleRowAction(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Responses from cacheable apex are read only. You are trying to add a property to the "opp" objects that you got back. You need to clone the objects in order to make them writable.

Comment: Next time please post full error include stacktrace. Stacktrace will help identify line causing the issue so community can you faster.